# If a promise object is set inside a function , will the promise object get removed from memory once the function is completed?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I was wondering if I use fetch method to return a promise object to handle asynchronous operation inside a function looks like this:

```
<script>
    function test(){
        let promise = fetch("https://xxx");
        promise.then(()=>{console.log("completed!")});
    };
    test()
</script>
```

This will work but my question is once the function test() is executed completely, according to the basic in Javascript where "Function (local) variables are deleted when the function is completed." , my thought is that the promise variable will get deleted and the actual promise object sits somewhere in the memory would have 0 reference, so it would get deleted by javascript. But it still work

Is it the implementation of Promise object sets it work differently in Javascript?

Thank you so much!!

**Update 1** : Sorry for my dumb mistake for not declaring promise variable with let or var . Here to add it on. Thanks!

Comment: This is likely bad code.  Because you did not declare your `promise` variable to be a local variable of the function, it will becomes an implicit global and will NOT get garbage collected because it's a global.  If you declare it locally with `let`, `const` or `var` in that function, then it will be garbage collected when the promise was done and the function was complete.

Comment: "*the actual promise object that sits somewhere in the memory would have 0 reference*" - the `promise` variable is not the only reference to the promise. There's also the reference that the `fetch` operation has to the promise, to resolve it when the request finishes.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is not a local variable. By declaring `promise` without a keyword, you have created a global variable attached to the window.

If you use the `let` or `const` keyword, you will declare a block-scoped variable, which will be garbage collected at the discretion of the system after its use. (Or even `var` in this case will scope it to the function)

```js
function test(){
    const promise = fetch("https://xxx");
    promise.then(()=>{console.log("completed!")});
};
```

Note the `const`*

Comment: Thanks for your kind reminder @skara9 .

Answer (score 1):

The variables will not be deleted from memory, unless there is no more pointers to the variables. There is a garbage collector in javascript responsible for checking the references and freeing the memory whenever it is possible (You can read more about it here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management ).
So When the functions finished, you cannot access the variable directly, but the memory still remains since there is a pointer to the promise that would change the state of the promise depending on the result of the action (fulfilled or rejected).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So when the function finished, even if the promise variable (local variable) has been removed, there is still another pointer to the actual promise object. The point is only when the promise has been fulfilled or rejected , then this object would probably get removed by Javascript memory management system.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect code.

Because you did not declare your `promise` variable to be a local variable of the function, it will becomes an implicit global and will NOT get garbage collected because it's a global.

If you declare it locally with `let`, `const` or `var` in that function (so it is a local variable within that function), then it will be garbage collected when the promise was done and the function was complete.

So, if you do this instead:

```
<script>
    function test(){
        const promise = fetch("https://xxx");
        promise.then(()=>{console.log("completed!")});
    };
    test()
</script>
```

Then, it will be garbage collected when the function and promise are done.

You should explicitly declare ALL variables with `let` or `const` in the scope in which you wish to use them.  While `var` still works (for backward compatibility reasons), there are no reasons to use it any more.